# Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class<ru.zabbkit.android.ui.activity.SlideMenuActivity>)'

Tags: java, android

пытаюсь запустить приложение скаченное с GitHub, не могу понять в чём ошибка, прошу помощи
[![Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class)'][1]][1]

Comment: не надо код скрином - выложите его текстом. По сути вопроса - у вас почему-то `String` вместо контекста передаётся... Это выглядит невозможным, но должно помочь передача `this`, вместо `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: Посkе добавления this ругается на следующее: error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(LoginActivity,Class<SlideMenuActivity>)
constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; LoginActivity cannot be converted to String)
constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; LoginActivity cannot be converted to Context)

Comment: Видимо у вас Login activity это вовсе не активити. Покажите код текстом - по скрину мы вам помочь точно не сможем. Для этого исправьте вопрос через [правку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/977967/edit)

Comment: Вы или неработающий код скачали или его самостоятельно неработающим сделали... Переопределять методы типа `getContext`, `getIntent()` и прочие - точно не надо. Большая часть кода просто должна быть выкинута. Помочь тут вряд ли возможно.

Comment: ЮрийСПБ, да я пытался сам исправить код, но  как вы заметили не удачно, я исправил вопрос там старый код с GitHub

Comment: Ошибка всё та же? По виду код должен работать. Странно, если getApplicationContext() возвращает строку.

Comment: да но этот код выдаёт кучу ошибок:error: LoginActivity is not abstract and does not override abstract method runOnUiThread(Runnable) in LoadingDialogActivity 
error: cannot find symbol method finish() 
error: cannot find symbol method startActivity(Intent) 
error: cannot find symbol method getSupportActionBar() 
error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int) 
error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int) 
error: cannot find symbol method getIntent() 
error: incompatible types: LoginActivity cannot be converted to Context

Comment: я и пытался таким способом методы объявить, но похоже это не правильно

Comment: Смотрите в иерархию наследования. У вас в приведённом коде явно имеется в виду, что класс - наследник класса `Activity`. Но, раз ругается на непереопределённые методы - значит проблема в super-классе. Смотрите что не так в LoadingDialogActivity и его супер классах. Возможно у вас какие-то библиотеки не подключены или вообще код настолько стар, что просто не поддерживает, например, систему сборки современную.

Comment: как раз  там всё нормально ошибок никаких нет

Comment: Ну... В таком случае, возможно, стоит удалить приведённый вами код вовсе из проекта. Т.к. он должен наследоваться от активити. Если это не так - вы не сможете заставить его работать. Выглядит всё так, что вы пытаетесь заставить работать в принципе некомпилируемую версию исходников.

Comment: у меня некоторые библиотеки выделены серым: import android.content.pm.PackageManager;  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager; import android.view.ContextMenu;import android.view.MenuItem; - это можно считать ошибкой? и если да, где эти библиотеки можно найти?

Comment: Это не ошибки. Это просто импорты неиспользуемые. Их можно игнорировать или удалить - это ни на что не повлияет. Библиотеки надо смотреть в `build.gradle`. Лучше посмотрите в исходниках что за версию кода вы пытаетесь запустить. Выглядит как брошенный на середине проект. Возможно вам надо использовать более старую версию исходников.

Comment: а версию кода вы имеете в виду SDKversion?

Comment: Нет... Версия кода в системе контроля версий, в `Git`. Т.е. в репозитории на GitHub должны лежать все версии исходников от момента создания проекта. Это надо смотреть на сайте GitHub-a

Comment: спасибо, посмотрю

Comment: Дам совет - столь древний и заброшенный проект трудно будет собрать без солидного опыта в андроид разработке. Мучаться долго будете, а результат маловероятен(

Comment: ЮрийСПб, всё исправил - поменял ActionBarActivity на  AppCompatActivity и почти все ошибки исчезли, спасибо вам, теперь ошибок в активити нет, приложение компилируется но не запускается  - думаю это ошибка уже в xml файлах

Comment: Не уверен, что я действительно вам чем-то помог)

Comment: ну хоть что-то) а так я никак не мог сдвинуться с места(

Comment: Удачи вам) Если получится запустить - получите немало полезного опыта)

Comment: ЮрийСПб, спасибо)